# python script to handle uploaded file via http post

Tags: python, django, post

I am working on a django project where i try to upload a file via http post request.

my upload script is :

```
url=r'http://MYSITEURL:8000/upload'
files={'file':open('1.png','rb')}
r=requests.post(url,files=files)
```

my receiving side is in my django site , in views.py:

```
def upload_image(request):
from py_utils import open_py_shell;open_py_shell.open_py_shell()
```

when i do request.FILES i can see all the post details, 
what i want to know is how to save it in the server side once i got the post request

Comment: Looks like you've solved 'script to upload file' and you're trying to solve 'handle uploaded file'. You should probably change your title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have in `request.FILES` is `InMemoryUploadedFile`. You just need to save it somewhere in file system.

This is example method taken from [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/file-uploads/):

```
def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    with open('some/file/name.txt', 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
```

Comment: it is not clear why `+` file mode is used (the destination is write-only) -- is it some permission-related hack? It is also not clear why `shutil.copyfileobj(f, destination)` is not used.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can work with models well. It will be the right way for Django. Here is an example, *models.py* file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

import os
import hashlib


def instanced_file(instance, filename):
    splitted_name = filename.split('.')
    extension = splitted_name[-1]
    return os.path.join('files', hashlib.md5(str(instance.id).encode('UTF-8')).hexdigest() + '.' + extension)

class File(models.Model):
    name = models.FileField('File', upload_to = instanced_file)

    def get_file_url(self):
        return '%s%s' % (settings.MEDIA_URL, self.name)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

After the creating models create forms and go on.